# Registros com datas recorrentes filtrados por um período

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, data, desempenho

## O Problema

Estou criando um sistema financeiro onde preciso registrar uma movimentação recorrente, como por exemplo, uma conta de luz que se repete todo mês. No sistema, esse tipo de movimentação é tratado como uma despesa/receita fixa.

A minha tabela possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
 [tabela de movimentações]
 - id                // Código do registro (int, auto increment)
 - title             // Um título para a movimentação (var_char)
 - description       // Descrição da movimentação (text)
 - type              // Se é receita ou despesa (tinyint)
 - repeat            // Tipo de repetição (tinyint)
 - is_recurring      // Se é uma movimentação recorrente ou não (tinyint)
 - start_date        // Data de início (timestamp)
 - value             // valor da movimentação (decimal) só preenchido se for recorrente
```

O campo `repeat` grava um inteiro que representa o intervalo de repetição, sendo eles:

```
0 - Nunca
1 - Todos os dias
2 - Toda semana
3 - A cada duas semanas
4 - Todo mês
5 - A cada dois meses
6 - A cada três meses
7 - A cada seis meses
8 - Todo ano
```

Se a movimentação não for recorrente e tiver parcelas predefinidas, seja uma ou várias, já ficam gravadas em outra tabela que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
 [tabela de parcelas]
 - id                // Código do registro (int, auto increment)
 - value             // valor da movimentação (decimal)
 - date              // Data da parcela (date)
 - status            // Status da parcela (tinyint) pago, pendente...
 - trasanction_id    // Referencia á primeira tabela para conseguir recuperar todas as 
                     // parcelas envolvidas em uma movimentação
```

Assim consigo recuperar todas as movimentações parceladas, mas o meu problema são as recorrentes, que só entram para a tabela de parcelas depois de serem efetivadas.

Como montar uma previsão de gastos futuros considerando essas movimentações recorrentes.

Não posso sair adicionando vários registros na tabela de parcelas até uma determinada data, pois se um relatório é gerado para um período superior ao do último registro, o usuário tomaria decisões erradas sem saber que aquela receita/despesa fixa não foi considerada.

A solução pode ser uma mescla de PHP e MySQL desde que não fique muito pesado.

### Exemplo

Possuo uma receita de R$ 10,00 reais que recebo toda semana a partir de 04/08/2014.

A do dia 04/08/2014 já foi quitada e já foi registrada na tabela de parcelas como paga. As futuras ainda não.

Preciso listar todas as receitas no período de 01/08/2014 a 05/09/2014.

A receita acima deve aparecer nas datas 04/08, 11/08, 18/08, 25/08 e 01/09 nesta listagem

## Soluções encontradas que não atenderam

Encontrei algumas soluções, que cito a seguir:

### Possível solução 1

Nesta solução é usado uma tabela para armazenar quando os dados devem se repetir, usando um mecanismo semelhante ao cron. Funciona, porem a performance é horrível para casos de relatórios de vários dias.

A consulta usada na solução é baseada na conta sobre um dia específico, sendo assim, para montar um relatório mensal, irei realizar 30 consultar no banco, e para um relatório anual, 365 consultas.

- [Calendar Recurring/Repeating Events - Best Storage Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183630/calendar-recurring-repeating-events-best-storage-method)
- [Repeating calendar events and some final maths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545869/repeating-calendar-events-and-some-final-maths)

### Possível solução 2

Esta solução utiliza uma tabela calendário. Uma solução quebra galho, que pode trazer muitos problemas futuros de manutenção, como a falta de datas cadastradas na tabela calendário, volume de registros armazenados sem necessidade, etc.

- [Recorrência de Datas com MySQL](http://www.hufersil.com.br/post/recorrencia-de-datas-com-mysql)

Comment: Acredito que seria melhor gerar vários registros e lincar esses registros a uma conta recorrente, daí na hora de gerar você pergunta para o usuário quanto acaba e qual a recorrência, então você gera todas as parcelas até a data de fim. se não for assim tudo vai ficar complicado, pense nos relatórios que você terá que gerar

Comment: Esse tipo de movimentação não possui data de termino, e é justamente por causa dos relatórios que preciso disso. O cadastro de movimentação como receita/despesa fixa é usado para realizar uma previsão. Se eu colocar sempre uma data final, a pessoa pode se esquecer e cometer um grave erro de administração por achar que na previsão aquela movimentação estava sendo considerada.

Comment: Vejo vários problemas na saída desejada. Um deles, por exemplo: se mudar o valor, você cancela o lançamento passado, perde todo o histórico e faz novo evento? Tabelas intermediárias nessas aplicações não são meras facilitadoras, mas sim formas de manter a consistência. Uma das soluções mais simples é uma tabela com um evento "rolante", que se atualizasse a cada lançamento deixando rastros no passado (no momento correto, o evento larga um clone no histórico, e se agenda pra data futura). O evento rolante é uma perspectiva do futuro, e a tabela de ocorrências guarda o que aconteceu de fato.

Comment: Já estou guardando o que ocorreu de fato em uma outra tabela, este não é o problema, eu mantenho o histórico. O problema é recuperar os dados futuros. Por exemplo, tenho uma conta trimestral, que iniciou em 10/07/2014, se eu solicitar um relatório para o mês 08 essa conta não aparece, mas em um relatório do mês 10 irá aparecer. Se eu pedir um relatório de 1/07/2014 a 30/11/2014 essa conta tem que aparecer duas vezes

Comment: Neste caso não posso clonar o dado após algo acontecer, pois necessito de montar previsões futuras, isto é, preciso realizar calculos que considerem o registro recorrente.

Comment: @marcusagm, acho que entendi completamente errado sua duvida... removi minha resposta para não poluir.

Comment: Tudo bem @papa-charlie, essa dúvida ta bem difícil de chegar em uma conclusão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode gerar os registros novos à medida em que eles são necessários, utilizando uma estratégia lazy. Assim, se o usuário indicar que ele quer saber das despesas até maio do ano que vem, por exemplo, você gera. No entanto, há um problema chato de consistência que é o valor da despesas recorrente ser reajustado (por exemplo, meu condomínio aumentou).

Com isso, você pode manter sim as tabelas separadas e exibir sempre as despesas já confirmadas separadas das estimativas para despesas recorrentes.

Eu sugiro também que você use um par (número, unidade) em vez do seu modelo atual. Como está, você não consegue representar, por exemplo, 5 semanas ou 10 meses.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução seria uma procedures retornando cursores ou até views montando estas tabelas virtuais, dependeria da reutilização destas informações.
Mas não vejo muitos incovenientes em gravar estes eventos futuros, eles seriam modificados quando ocorrecem.

Comment: Os motivos de não querer gravar os dados futuros são: 1) Um número muito alto de registros gerado atoa no sistema. 2) Tempo de processamento para atualização de todos os registros futuros caso haja alguma alteração. 3) Limitar o sistema para trabalhar até um limite máximo de anos, pois para cadastrar os dados futuros preciso ter uma data final. 4) Possibilidade de erro de decisão, o usuário gerar um relatório cujo a movimentação era para ser considerada mas não foi porque as movimentações futuras foram cadastradas até uma data anterior, o usuário não está ciente disto.

Comment: O motivo 4 eu posso resolver com o cron, para sempre verificar e cadastrar as que faltam, mas para isso teria que realmente limitar meu sistema para gerar relatório para um período máximo. Isso impede que sejam feitas projeções de um longo período pelo sistema.

Comment: Sobre a reutilização do dados, eles são constantemente acessados, seja para gerar gráficos de visão geral, alertas, relatórios simples ou completos.

Comment: Pelo que entendi seriam dados que serão realizados , uma informação do tipo previsto x realizado resolve a questão da separação do dado.Sql é bom para obter dados gravados, dados "faltates" podem ser montados via artificios mas em geral não são boas soluções.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem o intervalo do relatório em numero de dias, porque não utilizar regra de 3 simples? Por exemplo, se a recorrência é de 15 em 15 dias e o período é de 60 dias a partir de hoje, você terá 4 parcelas. O saldo devedor seria 60/15*valor_parcela.

Como você já tem um código Tinyint que representa o tipo de recorrência, bastaria você associa-lo a um tamanho de intervalo. Evidentemente as datas que já passaram estariam fora do intervalo.